# How to handle multiple inputs to create nested state property

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**My code to handle multiple inputs**

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import "./QueryToParameter.css";

    const [parameters, setParameter] = useState([]);
    
        const onQueryChange = (e) => {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            setParameter(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                [name]: value,
            }));
        }
    
        const onParameterChange = (e) => {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            setParameter(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                parametri: { ...prevState.parametri, [name]: value }
            }));
        }
    
        const onDbParameterChange = (e) => {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            setParameter(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                dbQueryParam: { ...prevState.dbQueryParam, [name]: value }
            }));
        }
    
        const onReport = () => {
            // AuthService.getReport(parameters).then((res) => {
            //     setParameter(res.data);
            //     console.log(res.data);
            // });
            console.log(parameters);
        }
```

**Form  code**

```
    return (
                <div>
                    <div className="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
                        <form>
                            <div className="col-12">
                                <label htmlFor="id" className="form-label">Query id</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="id" value={parameters.value} onChange={onQueryChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-12">
                                <label htmlFor="opis" className="form-label">Query opis</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="opis"  value={parameters.value} onChange={onQueryChange} />
                            </div>
                                <ul>
                                    <div className="col-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="id" className="form-label">Parametar id</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="id" value={parameters.value} onChange={onParameterChange} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="ime" className="form-label">Parametar ime</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="ime" value={parameters.value} onChange={onParameterChange} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="opis" className="form-label">Parametar opis</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="opis" value={parameters.value} onChange={onParameterChange} />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="duzina" className="form-label">Parametar duzina</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="duzina" value={parameters.value} onChange={onParameterChange} />
                                    </div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <div className="col-12">
                                            <label htmlFor="id" className="form-label">DB Parametar id</label>
                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="id"  value={parameters.value} onChange={onDbParameterChange} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-12">
                                            <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">DB Parametar name</label>
                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name"  value={parameters.value} onChange={onDbParameterChange} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-12">
                                            <label htmlFor="opis" className="form-label">DB Parametar opis</label>
                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="opis"  value={parameters.value} onChange={onDbParameterChange} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-12">
                                            <label htmlFor={parametar.dbQueryParam.tip} className="form-label">DB Parametar tip</label>
                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="tip" value={parameters.value} onChange={onDbParameterChange} />
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div className="col-12">
                                        <label htmlFor="vrednost" className="form-label">Vrednost</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="vrednost"  value={parameters.value} onChange={onDbParameterChange} />
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            <div className="col-12">
                                <label htmlFor="requestType" className="form-label">Query requestType</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="requestType"  value={parameters.value} onChange={onQueryChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-12">
                                <label htmlFor="oznaka" className="form-label">Query oznaka</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="oznaka" value={parameters.value} onChange={onQueryChange} />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary mt-4 mb-4" onClick={onReport}>Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**How to get this array of objects in state**

{
"id": 1,
"opis": "Some text...",
"parametri": [
{
"id": 101,
"ime": "Some text...",
"opis": "Some text...",
"duzina": 12,
"dbQueryParam": {
"id": 2,
"name": "Some text...",
"opis": "Some text...",
"tip": "Some text..."
},
"vrednost": 1234
}
],
"requestType": "Some text...",
"oznaka": "Some text..."
}

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem with the parameters from API.**

```
const [links, setLink] = useState([]);
const [vrednostP, setVrednost] = useState([]);
let id = parseInt(useParams().id);
let linkP = links.map(link => link.id).indexOf(id);
let link = (links[linkP]);

const onReport = () => {
    const param = {
                    id: link.id,
                    opis: link.opis,
                    parametri: [
                        {
                            id: link.parametri[0].id,
                            ime: link.parametri[0].ime,
                            opis: link.parametri[0].opis,
                            duzina: link.parametri[0].duzina,
                            dbQueryParam: {
                                id: link.parametri[0].dbQueryParam.id,
                                name: link.parametri[0].dbQueryParam.name,
                                opis: link.parametri[0].dbQueryParam.opis,
                                tip: link.parametri[0].dbQueryParam.tip
                            },
                            vrednost: vrednostP,
                        }
                    ],
                    requestType: link.requestType,
                    oznaka: link.oznaka
                }
                AuthService.getReport(param).then((res) => {
                    setVrednost(res.data);
                    console.log(res.data);
                });
}
```